# Visual Studio Windows Service c# exe file missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I write and install windows services in another computer but I can't find exe file of my solution in Project/bin/debug.

here way of the install I used :

- open cmd for visual studio developers.
- cd windows/microsoft.net/framework
- install.exe project exe file (i can't find it)

Comment: what ever the build , it will be there in your project folder only unless if you dont copy there it wont be available any other location. If you want to add it ti GAC then register it as GAC so that it will available in GAC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio for your service implementation, open that solution in Visual Studio, and right click on the windows service project and click Properties.

In the properties window, Select the Build tab on the right hand side, and then find the Output section which will tell you the output path of the exe.

This way you con locate where the exe file of your service is.

To install the service, you do not have to navigate to windows/microsoft.net/framework location when you open visual studio developer command prompt. Instead, navigate to the folder where your project.exe resides and then call install project.exe

Hope this helps