# Visual Studio 2019 Solution does not build exe file for Windows Service Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Recently converted VB.NET solution from Visual Studio 2013 4.0 Framework to Visual Studio 2019 4.8 Framework. The solution contains 22 project. Of the 22 projects there is one Windows Form Application and one Windows Service project.

In Visual Studio 2013, compiling the solution would create two .exe files. One for the Windows Form project and another for the windows service project.

After converting to Visual Studio 2019 and compiling the solution, there is only one .exe file being created. That .exe file is for the Windows Form project (startup project).

When solution was being compiled using VS 2013, both .exe files would get created.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get VS 2019 to create the two .exe output files when compiling? Thanks

Comment: Double-check in Build / Configuration Manager that both projects are set to be built for the active solution configuration.  When I've had something not generated in the past, it was because the project was not set to be built for the active configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both projects are checked for "Build" in configuration manager. Actually, all projects are checked. Thanks

Comment: Can you find the Windows Service exe file on his [output path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987616/12666543)? Try to re-install the workload ‘.NET desktop development’